# How to do port forwarding when there is a bastion box infront of linux server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, portforwarding

I have a ec2 server and it has a bastion box/server Infront of it. I can't ssh to ec2 server directly and have to go through to the bastion box. I have a db server running PostgreSQL on rds. I am trying to do port forwarding to the port where my DB server is running but can't figure out how to do with that bastion box present.

In my dev environment, there is no bastion box and I can ssh to ec2 server using putty. putty is already configured to local port forward the port to DB server port. this works , but I have no idea how to do with bastion box. Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both EC2 and RDS should be in same VPC.

You should have allowed Ec2 security group with required port both inbound and outbound

In RDS you should have another security group which opens the same port

source option should be EC2 security group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same configuration as your Dev environment, but use PuTTy with Port Forwarding to the Bastion server.

- Configure the Security Group on the RDS instance to accept incoming requests from the Bastion server (preferably by referring to the name of the Security Group that is assigned to the Bastion Server)
- SSH into the Bastion server, with port forwarding configured (see below)
- Point your local SQL client to `localhost:5432`

In PuTTy, use the **Tunnels** command to configure:

- **Source port:** `5432` (Could be anything, but this is the standard for PostgreSQL)
- **Destination:** `<RDS DNS Name>:5432` (Insert the DNS Name that you use to connect to the RDS instance)

This means that traffic sent to port 5432 on your own computer (`localhost:5432`) will be sent to the Bastion and will then be sent to port 5432 on the RDS server. The traffic will *pass through* the Bastion.